# Supporting ideas for php over .net

Tags: php, .net, iphone

I am a newly graduated programmer. I have done many web pages and services with Php.

I took a project as a freelancer. My employer want the web site to be coded mainly with Php. He took another employee as a iphone developer. 
iphone developer guy want to write web services with .NET while i have no idea about it. (ı have done some windows application with .Net)
And this iphone develpor guy also want to code the web site with .Net not PHP.

I dont know his arguments but my argument is, i dont know .net as well as i do PHP.

Tomorrow we 3 going to have a meeting.
I am really nervous about it.

iPhone guy can ask me why do you develop with Php, let us do it with .Net.
can you give me some supporting arguments on my side.

he thinks that developing web services with .net and developing the web site with php would be hard and inefficient. do you think this is true? or is he want to take the job fully?

Comment: Seeing as you just graduated, learning another language/platform will not be bad for your career. If you don't know .NET, learn.

Comment: I'm not going to go into comparing .NET with PHP, but one argument you could make is that PHP runs on many platforms, while .NET will tie your employer to Windows, with the licensing costs that come with it. Only an argument if they're free to choose their platform though.

Comment: The choice of the platform will not affect the price of hosting. You will need to pay for PHP hosting in the same way as you are paying for ASP.NET hosting.
Actually big number of PHP hosting companies use Windows and IIS as a hosting platform.

Comment: .Net runs just fine on linux using Mono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, congratulations on graduation, but now your real schooling begins as a professional!

So first to clarify, a web-service is usually a page/url/etc. that provides data to a requester based upon some parameters that you pass to it.  It will often return a formatted result in some mark-up language like XML, or XML based formats like SOAP or REST. An example of this would be Google Maps API web service, where you can dynamically embed a map into a web page based upon parameters that you pass to the Google web service.

With a web service that provides XML it doesn't matter what language you use to interpret and process that XML response, as XML is pretty easy parse using standard issue .NET/PHP XML parsing functions/objects.  Therefore I think the iPhone developer is getting his panties in a twist unnecessarily.  If you know PHP, then you could build a web service that provides a XML feed in the necessary format.

I am biased because I like PHP over .NET, but still its only difficult if you don't know what to do...???

Best of luck with your meeting!  Stand strong and don't let yourself be bullied.

Comment: ha di didee doo dot wah da da

Answer (score 1):

> He took another employee as a iphone
>   developer.

Is it like this, that the iphone-guy makes an iphone-app that accesses webservices from your website. And you are mainly programming the website? The programmer that have to work the most time on the website (and therefore the webservices) should decide with which programming-language he wants to work. So this developer can be more efficient.

The Iphone-Guy should stick on Iphone-Apps and you should provide him the web-services the best way you can do that. Which means PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do anything you want either in PHP or in ASP.NET. Both platforms have a lot of frameworks and tools. Neither of choices will limit your ability of creating whatever web-solution you need. The question is always about productivity and cost.

I did both coding PHP and ASP.NET. Coding with ASP.NET and especially in Visual Studio is much more productive than coding PHP in any editor. If you will invest the same amount of time in learning both platforms, ASP.NET will yield unquestionably better results.

There are people out there who will claim that PHP is more productive than ASP.NET because they are more productive in PHP than other developers in ASP.NET. In reality, those people compare themselves with programmers who did not invest as many years in learning ASP.NET as they invested in learning PHP.

The main argument for you will be that you already know PHP. You will be able to deliver results in PHP faster than with any other platform.  This argument will overweight any technical argument if your customer is concern with delivering his product fast.

Answer (score 0):

> iPhone guy can ask me why do you develop with Php, let us do it with .Net. can you give me some supporting arguments on my side.

Do the reverse. Ask him why he thinks that PHP is not good enough.

> he thinks that developing web services with .net and developing the web site with php would be hard and inefficient. do you think this is true? or is he want to take the job fully?

.Net webservices is usually done using SOAP. php has excellent support for SOAP and it can [generate PHP web service skeletons](http://www.mehtanirav.com/2009/01/28/wsdl-to-php-generate-php-code-from-a-wsdl-file) by using the WSDL file that defines the SOAP service.

When coding web services against phones it can be better to create a restful web service which exposes the data using [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) (less bandwidth than xml). Simple take an existing framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/).

ohh. I've been a .NET guy for the past years. I do have coded my fair amount of PHP sites (prior to  .NET). The language/platform is not really important. It's your skills that count. Do use what you know when you can make money, and play with other languages in your spare time.